# Double-struck unicode chars in \texorpdfstring

Tags: unicode

Consider the following example (PDFLaTeX, TeXLive 2011):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace,amssymb,mathtools,fixltx2e}
% This isn't *stricly* necessary, of course...
\ifdefined\TextOrMath
  \def\ensuremath#1{\TextOrMath{\(\relax #1\)}{#1}}
\fi
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\def\defTeXorMathorUnicodePDFcmd#1#2#3{%
  \def#1{\texorpdfstring{\ensuremath{#2}}{#3}\xspace}}
% Common double-struck characters such as ℂ, ℍ, ℕ, ℙ, ℚ, ℝ and ℤ are
% set up to work by inputenc.sty.  They are in the range u+2102-2149
% along with some other characters that aren't in amsmath's blackboard
% bold font such as ⅆ and ⅈ.
\defTeXorMathorUnicodePDFcmd\CC{\mathbb C}{ℂ}
%  is an example of a character that inputenc.sty doesn't make work. 
% It - along with the characters , , , &c - are in the completely 
% different range u+1D538-1D7E1.
\defTeXorMathorUnicodePDFcmd\FF{\mathbb F}{}
\begin{document} \section{\CC and \FF, [\ldots]} \end{document}
```

The purpose of `\CC` is to get ℂ in both the text and the PDF TOC when used in for example a section header.  What's needed to get `\FF` to do the same for  (and similarly for the other "uncommon" double-struck characters)?

PS: I copied the characters from here: http://graphemica.com/search?q=double+struck

Comment: I can see both ℂ and  in the bookmark, both with Skim and Adobe Reader.

Comment: I feel like an idiot... in my original file, I had those macro definitions *before* `\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}`.  Of course Adobe Reader doesn't display the double-struck F because its UI font is missing the glyph, but moving the definitions of `\FF` and friends to after hyperref did fix the problems I was having with pdflatex giving errors.

Comment: I don't get errors even putting the definitions before loading `hyperref`

Comment: But you made me encounter a valid problem trying to understand yours... And now I'd like to have it solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*This is not an proper answer, but an analysis of the problem.*

The problem seems pdf-viewer dependent. I see  in the bookmarks with Adobe Reader, but not with Evince (a Linux pdf-viewer). The error message hints at the source of the error : it says that ' \xed\xa0\xb5\xed\xb4\xbd' (for ) is not a valid UTF8 sequence. Indeed, it is not a UTF-8 byte sequence, but a [CESU-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CESU-8) sequence. They are indistinguishable most of the common characters (on the [basic multilingual plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Multilingual_Plane#Basic_Multilingual_Plane)), but  is on another plane.

I don't know whether the pdf-format wants UTF-8 or CESU-8 encoded text, so I don't know if the bug is on the pdf generation side (in pdflatex) or on the viewer side.